# Does Ubuntu's disk encryption work along side Windows 10 in a dual boot system?

Tags: encryption

This question is in regard to a development machine that is dual boot. I have source code I want to protect on both the Ubuntu side and the Windows 10 side. Does Ubuntu's disk encryption work along side Windows 10 in a dual boot system and would each side be protected by its respective encryption system?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It is called disk encryption, but in fact it encrypts partitions and will not encrypt your Windows 10 partition if you don't let it.

Comment: How do you keep it from grabbing the whole drive?

Comment: What kind of encryption do you use?

Comment: I'm thinking of the system, that is offered by the installer Ubiquity: LVM with LUKS encryption. Maybe you cn suggest a more flexible alternative for dual booting.

Comment: You will be asked during installation if you want to encrypt the partition that is being used for Ubuntu. You could, at that point, decide to encrypt other partitions as well.

Comment: Sounds like you are thinking of the old encrypted home option. That isn't offered in the new installer, only whole-disk encryption.